# Swift Syntax on |> and .~

Tags: swift, syntax

There is some Swift syntax that I don't understand...

```
let creator = .template |> User.lens.avatar.small .~ ""
```

Can someone tell me what the `|>` and `.~` syntax do?
I also see `%~` used.

If you can point out the location in the Swift documentation I would appreciate it. It's been difficult searching using these characters. I would like to see the full array of symbols.

Comment: where is that code from? You know you can define pretty much anything you want to be an operator like + and -? I would guess that are just two custom operators.

Comment: https://github.com/kickstarter/ios-oss/blob/master/Kickstarter-iOS/Tests/Views/ActivitiesViewControllerTests.swift

Comment: Like most things, operators can be command-clicked to view their declaration.

Comment: Xcode is not able to jump to the definition and a text search shows 3249 results. Perhaps it is defined in a library. They make us of "React" and several others.

Comment: Option click the operands to see what type they are, that will give you a clue.

Comment: https://github.com/ReactKit/ReactKit#stream-pipelining

Comment: Ok, I see it now.  Thank  you Martin R.

Comment: The other one... https://github.com/kickstarter/Kickstarter-Prelude/blob/247c4f779d6e5bc76289e8c0331155f8221af3b7/Prelude/Operators.swift#L25-L26

Comment: The most important thing to learn here is that custom operators are bad because it's impossible to Google them.

Answer (score 4):

## Stream Pipelining

Streams can be composed by using `|>` stream-pipelining operator and Stream Operations.

For example, a very common incremental search technique using `searchTextStream` will look like this:

```
let searchResultsStream: Stream<[Result]> = searchTextStream
    |> debounce(0.3)
    |> distinctUntilChanged
    |> map { text -> Stream<[Result]> in
        return API.getSearchResultsStream(text)
    }
    |> switchLatestInner
```

There are some scenarios (e.g. `repeat()`) when you want to use a cloneable `Stream<T>.Producer` (`Void -> Stream<T>`) rather than plain `Stream<T>`. In this case, you can use `|>>` streamProducer-pipelining operator instead.

```
// first, wrap stream with closure
let timerProducer: Void -> Stream<Int> = {
    return createTimerStream(interval: 1)
        |> map { ... }
        |> filter { ... }
}

// then, use `|>>`  (streamProducer-pipelining operator)
let repeatTimerProducer = timerProducer |>> repeat(3)
```

But in the above case, wrapping with closure will always become cumbersome, so you can also use `|>>` operator for Stream & Stream Operations as well (thanks to @autoclosure).

```
let repeatTimerProducer = createTimerStream(interval: 1)
    |>> map { ... }
    |>> filter { ... }
    |>> repeat(3)
```